# How to execute a python script stored in AWS S3 using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script stored in one of my S3 buckets, I want to create a lambda function to execute this python script along with passing parameters to my python script.

Things I tried -

I am successfully able to read my python script from the lambda handler function using boto3.
Created the environment variables successfully to pass to my python script.
Got a few answers from Stackoverflow that I can copy the script to /tmp and then import and execute. That is not working.

Question - Reading is fine but how to execute the python script.

Let me know the options.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you do it on your local workstation?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your end-goal? Why do you wish to execute a Python script from S3 within a Lambda function? Why not just put the code in the Lambda function itself? Please note that it is potentially dangerous since any code in the file will execute with the permissions of the Lambda function, which isn't good security practice.

Answer (score 0):

we can create one more AWS Lamba and call from main Lambda. For this you need to create a IAM role to execute the Lambda from Lambda.